# Return functions in Javascript D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm running into trouble with returning values through a return function. The D3 data container (d) is holding all the data that is bound at the beginning of the parent function call.

```
function getPointsFromStop(xScale, yScale, d, relative) {
      var last = null;
      var stops = d.stops.map(function (stop) {
        // special case: place-jfk, place-nqncy -> place-jfk, place-asmnl (at same time), place-nqncy 
        // special case: place-nqncy, place-jfk -> place-nqncy, place-asmnl (at same time), place-jfk
        var result;
        if (last && last.stop === 'place-jfk' && stop.stop === 'place-nqncy') {
          result = [null, {stop: 'place-asmnl', time: last.time}, stop];
        } else if (last && last.stop === 'place-nqncy' && stop.stop === 'place-jfk') {
          result = [{stop: 'place-asmnl', time: stop.time}, null, stop];
        } else {
          result = [stop];
        }
        last = stop;
        return result;
      });
      var flattenedStops = _.flatten(stops);
      var startX = xScale(header[d.stops[0].stop + '|' + d.line][0]);
      var points = flattenedStops.map(function (stop) {
        if (!stop) { return null; }
        var y = yScale(stop.time) - yScale(flattenedStops[0].time);
        //console.log(stop.stop)
        var x = xScale(header[stop.stop + '|' + d.line][0]);
        if (relative) {
          x -= startX;
        }
        return [x, y];
      });
      return points;
    }

    function draw2(xScale, yScale, relative) {
      console.log("here")

      return function (d) {
        points = getPointsFromStop(xScale, yScale, d, relative);
        return points;
      };

    }
```

Original source code: https://github.com/mbtaviz/mbtaviz.github.io/blob/master/scripts/the-trains.js#L616

I modified the draw function to return points which is an array, instead of calling the linemapping function. However, my modified function is returning an anonymous function instead of the actual array, which is what we want.

Comment: What trouble are you running into? And what is your question?

Comment: An anonymous function is being returned when draw2 is called. What I'm looking for is the points array inside of it to be returned instead. So basically my question is how to make that work.

Comment: Well, the reason for that is because that's what you typed into the console... why not just do this: `return getPointsFromStop(xScale, yScale, d, relative);`

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by that

Comment: I mean the reason your function returns an anonimous function is because there is an anonimous function after the return statement in your function and I'm suggesting you replace that code with the snippet in my previous comment.

Comment: `function draw2(xScale, yScale, relative) {

      return getPointsFromStop(xScale, yScale, d, relative);

  }`

This is what I replaced the draw2 function with and I'm getting that d is not defined. Is this what you meant? Is there a way to get access to d that was bound to the parent function?